# Prove a function is a weak fibration.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

[image]

I'm having trouble proving that this is a weak fibration.  I can see that diagonal map for the commutative diagram of a fibration must be of the form $\tilde G(\bar t, t) = (G(\bar t, t), ? )$, but I'm not sure how to proceed to find the ? component.

I'm not really understanding how the hint can be applied either.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Note that $I^n$ is path connected for each $n$, so its image under a continuous map must lie in a path component of $E$.